# Show that for every $n$-primary root of unity that ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),\Bbb Q)$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, solvable-groups

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{5})$ and $G={\rm Gal}(K,\mathbb{Q})$. Show that for every $n$-primary root of unity that ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),\mathbb{Q})$ is solvable.

My approach untill I got stuck:

I found that $G\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. That means that every subgroup of $G$ is normal under $G$ (and of course every subfield of $K$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$, including $K$.

We know that $K$ is a root extension since the series:$\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{5})=K$ include every attribute needed.

Also $K(\zeta)$ is for sure a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is a splitting field itself.

From the above we can conclude that $G$ is solvable. Yet the question implies that ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),Q)$. Well since $K(\zeta)$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ then $G$ is a normal subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),Q)$. We  know for a group to be solvable, other than every subgroup of a subgroup etc being normal under each other, we need ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),Q)/G$ be abelian or because we have finite groups, we $|{\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),Q)/G|=p$ (prime number).

From the fundamenta theorem of Galois theory we know that ${\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),Q)/G \simeq{\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),K)$.
And thus we need $|{\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),K)|=p$ 
Since $K(\zeta)$ is a splitting field $\mathbb{Q}$, then naturally $K(\zeta)$ is a splitting field over $K$ and for that reason $|{\rm Gal}(K(\zeta),K)|=[K(\zeta):K]\leq \phi(n).$

This is where I don't know how to follow. I'm aware of a lemma saying:

> Let $F$ be a field that contains $n$-primary root of unity and $a \in \mathbb{C}$, for which $a^n \in F$. Then ${\rm Gal}(F(a),F)$ is solvable.

But was unable to use it somehow.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: For any root of unity $\zeta$, the extension $K(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ is the compositum of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ and $K/\Bbb Q$. Since both are abelian extensions, their compositum is again an abelian extension and hence solvable. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah that does the trick . How can I prove that $K(\zeta)$ is abelian since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ and $K$ are abelian ? Does it have something to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem? I understand it by sense,but mathematically is there a straightforward way to prove it ? Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the galois group of $K|\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ because the only operation you can do is the "conjugate", that's it
$$\sqrt2\rightarrow -\sqrt2\\
\sqrt5i\rightarrow -\sqrt5i\\$$
So it's an abelian extension.
Also the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)|\mathbb{Q}$ where $\zeta$ is any nth-root of the unity is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$, which is also abelian. So the galois group of $K(\zeta)|\mathbb{Q}$ must be abelian (1). It could be that $K(\zeta)=K$, for example if $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/8}$, because $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,i)$

To prove (1) just see that:
Let $ψ:Gal(EL/\mathbb{Q})→Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})×Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ be a map such that $ψ(σ)=(σ|E,σ|L)$ for every $\sigma$ automorphism of the composition. $ψ$ is clearly a group homomorphism and  it's easy to see that $ψ$ is injective. Hence Gal(KL/k) is abelian.

Comment: Are you sure that $Gal(K,\mathbb{Q})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ ?Also is the fact that the Galois group of $K(\zeta)$ abelian trivial using  that $Gal(K,\mathbb{Q})$ and $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta),Q)$ are abelian ?Thank you for your time !

Comment: Yeah im sure, note that the field extension is generated by 3 elements, every K-automorphism is defined by the images of the generators, and their images must be roots of their minimal polynomial, so we have 8 different automorphisms. By the second part i think that yes, its trivial

Comment: But $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ .If we consider the extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq K$ .We know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $i\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \Rightarrow [K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]\geq  2 $.Also $\pm i\sqrt{5}$ is root of  $x^2+5 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ ,that means that $Irr(i\sqrt{5},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))|x^2+5$ and thus $[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]\leq 2$.So we get $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ since we proved that $[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$. Is that wrong ?

Comment: I think you are confused. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5,i) \not=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5 \cdot i)$

Comment: Just note that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p, \sqrt q):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ if $gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: Yeah of course its not ,but Im working on the galois group of $K=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5},\sqrt{2}) $

Comment: Ups! Sorry i did not read it well. My apologies! Of course the group is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: ''Just note that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ if $gcd(p,q)=1$''.That's a nice trick i didnt know about !

Comment: It's okay! Thank you anyway !Your answer still applies !

Comment: In general it can be extended to a numerable family of primes $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p_1,....,\sqrt p_n)=2^n$

Comment: Great , I will keep that in mind ! Thank you !

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the crucial part: the compositum of two abelian extensions is again an abelian extension. This is a simple exercise in Galois theory but you need to solve it.